# Вторичное выполнение скрипта php

Tags: php, email

Кто знает, как можно реализовать повтор выполнения скрипта только один раз. Требуется выполнить повторно mail(...); через 120сек.

sleep() - не катит!

```
$dt = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
$mainBody = "Date: $dt\nPhone: $phone\nName: $name";
mail('info@myhost.ru', 'New app on site', $mainBody);
```

Comment: используйте крон или любой планировщик задач, который предоставляет Ваш фреймворк

Answer (score 0):

Чой-тоть `sleep` не катит? Вы просто не умеете им пользоваться видимо.

```php
$maxRepeatCount = 2;
$cnt = 0;

while ( $cnt < $maxRepeatCount ) {
    $dt = date("Y-d-m H:i:s");
    $mainBody = "Date: $dt\nPhone: $phone\nName: $name";
    mail('info@myhost.ru', 'New app on site', $mainBody);
    $cnt++;
    if ( $cnt < $maxRepeatCount ) { sleep(120); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}

if(!in_array($argv, "dublicator")){
   execInBackground('$SHELL -c "sleep 120 && php '.escapeshellarg($argv[0]).' dublicator"');
}
```

Я честно не знаю, будет ли это работать на винде, а вот на линуксах пойдет с любой версией PHP4+.

Скрипт запускает оболочку для выполнения команды, которая состоит из двух команд: первая `sleep 120` просто ждет 120 секунд, вторая `php $argv[0] dublicator` должна запустить текущий скрипт еще раз.

В условии мы проверяем наличие аргумента `dublicator` чтобы не зациклить процесс.